# Setting plot linestyles afterwards

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, linestyle

I am plotting graphs in a loop:

```
cities = grouped_price.index.levels[0]  # list of cities
dates  = grouped_price.index.levels[1]  # list of dates, which
                                        # are 1st day of each month
linestyles = ['-', '-.', '--', '-.-', ':']

for city in cities[0:1]:
    for month in dates:  # loop over dates, which are grouped by month
        legend = legend + [month.strftime("%B")] # month in text
        ax = grouped_price.loc[city, month]['Amount'].plot()
plt.show()
```

How can I set *linestyles* afterwards? If I write

```
ax = grouped_price.loc[city, week]['Amount'].plot(style = linestyles)
```

inside the loops, it just uses the first *linestyle* for all lines.

Same question with *colors* and line *thickness*. I found an iterative solution for setting thicknesses (loop over each line), but is there a simpler way? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the length of citites? I don't know of a way to plot them afterwards, but you should be able to work something out with `enumerate()` and the idx of linestyles, colors, and so on. Same question with weeks, can we have a working example?

Comment: Mathieu, right now I am actually plotting 1 city. And I changed weeks to months.
Georgy, desired output is 1 plot with 12 lines on it, where each line has a unique combination of style+color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provided you have the same number of months and linestyles, you can do:

```
linestyles = ['-', '-.', '--', '-.-', ':']
for city in cities[0:1]:
    for month,ls in zip(dates, linestyles):  # loop over dates, which are grouped by month and linestyles
        legend = legend + [month.strftime("%B")] # month in text
        ax = grouped_price.loc[city, month]['Amount'].plot(style = ls)
plt.show()
```